# How set HealthKit request authorization tableview appearance

Tags: ios8, xcode6, healthkit

I'm adding HealthKit to my app and I found all useful information on the apple developer page, but there's something that isn't explained.

When I call the method `requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:` a modal tableview appear asking user permission and I want to change it.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of the security model of how a user allows read/write access from your Healthkit app, you are not going to be able to change the modal table view.

From the discussion in the API for `requestAuthorizationToShareTypes`

> the system automatically displays the permission form, listing all the requested permissions.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKHealthStore/requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion: